# Compile my application written in visual studio 2003 with mfc for Windows CE 6.00

Tags: visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

I use Visual studio 2003. I have a program written in C + + using MFC how can I compile for WindowsCE 6:00? There is a tool to cross-compile from windows xp on my pc and then transfer the executable and libraries?

i dont have SDK for the WINDOWS EMBEDDED CE 6.0. Where i can download it for x86 windows ce 6.0?

in [Visual C++]->[Smart Device]->[MFC Smart Device Application]  i have only:

Smartphone 2003 for ARM

Pocket PC 2003 also for ARM

Where is x86 platform? my board have an ATOM BOARD!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows CE is a modular OS, Microsoft cannot ship an SDK that targets any arbitrary hardware.  They shipped SDKs for their own, closed-system builds.  For any other hardware you need to install a specific SDK.

The first step is to get an SDK from the device OEM.  Without an SDK, you're not going to be able to do much.  If you created the OS image (it doesn't sounds like you did, but in case you did), then you need to roll an SDK with the SDK roller tool in Platform Builder.

Once you have that, you still will have a fairly large task in getting the application to compile.  It's highly unlikely that the app will just compile as-is if you didn't initially set out to target Windows CE.  Expect desktop controls and APIs to not be present in Windows CE, and for classes to have fewer overloads.  Windows CE is also very highly biased toward Unicode, so if you have a lot of ANSI calls, especially to the OS, expect those to also need rework.

Basically, create a new application targeting your device, pull in all the source files, hit Build and then start fixing the compiler errors.